# What do the terms "special form" and "general form" mean in reference to an equation?

Tags: terminology

What do the terms "special form" and "general form" mean in reference to an equation?  Is the "standard form" the same as the general?

Comment: It is different from equation to equation exactly what each of those terms mean. Do you have a specific example in mind?

Comment: I'm looking at the formula for calculating the TALC (for Truth in Lending) in the U.S. Code of Federal Regulations.  Here's the link: https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=d5cf42c2d4663e1cadae1fe2f5c5afbc&node=pt12.9.1026&rgn=div5#ap12.9.1026.0000_0nbspnbspnbsp.k  Look at paragraphs (b)(7) and (8)